# Publishing .Net Core app to IIS fails if Visual Studio 2017 when "Delete Existing Files" option is selected

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, .net-core, publish

When trying to publish my .Net Core app to a remote IIS server I am unable to publish with the "Delete Existing Files" option selected. When I try I get hundreds of errors for each file saying: **Unable to remove ... The process cannot access the file ... because it is being used by another process.**

If I shut down the kestrel server or put app_offline.htm in the web folder I still get an error for the root folder of the web app: **Unable to remove directory "\remoteserver\webapp\". The process cannot access the file "\remoteserver\wenapp\' because it is being used by another process.**

I literally have to shut down IIS to publish which is not ideal. Any suggestions? I have made sure the permissions allow read an write to users.

Comment: The files are in use by IIS (as it is still serving them), as per the error message. You'll need stop IIS from serving your application and try to publish again. There should be an option for this in Visual Studio (I tend to publish from AppVeyor this days, so I can't remember what the option will be called in Visual studio)